# Is it possible to get attribute printf format checks on an expanded variadic template pack?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, printf

I'm trying to combine gcc's **compile-time checking of printf format strings** with c++11's **variadic template packs**.

I know I can decorate a variadic function with gcc's `__attribute__((format(__printf__, ...))` decorator.

I know I can expand a variadic template pack into a variadic function. eg: `printf(fmt, pack...);`

Is it possible to combine the two?

**Working example of what I'm trying to achieve:**

```
#include <iostream>

void check(const char*, ...) __attribute__((format(__printf__, 1, 2)));
void check(const char*, ...)
{ 
    // exists only for the purposes of catching bogus format strings
}

template<typename... Ts>
void check_t(const char fmt[], Ts... ts)
{
    // check the format string by expanding ts into the check function
    check(fmt, ts...);
}

int main()
{
    const char f[] = "foo %s";
    check_t(f, 5);              // compiles
    check(f, 5);                // fails to compile
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user657267 - the answer you linked talks about string literals. I'm using a `const char []` being passed to both `check_t` and `check` - so gcc can obviously tell the difference - I guess I'm wondering if I can have gcc look at the input into the function template in the same way.